# Full-width image with links

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I need a full-width image with labeled sections to link to individual pages. Any suggestions how to make this happen? The web site is built on WordPress, so if a plug-in will accomplish this that will work too. Method needs to be responsive and not break apart as viewport is reduced.

For example, Section 1 needs to link to the Section 1 page, etc.
See image at [image: http://cl.ly/image/0H1L0k010x07]

Comment: nice thought for new design ..

Comment: <sarcasm>How about to make it with CSS, HTML and JS ?</sarcasm>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want to have something like that and responsive, you should cut the image in as many pieces as items you need, create an element for each piece and set the image as background. There rest is mediaqueries, maybe you can do it with bootstrap.

Also, try to go to the design community, as this is more related to design than anything else, and I don't think a Wordpress plugin exists for this.